# Survival's Risk score in R

Tags: r, survival, risk

How to obtain Risk score in R? Is the following approach correct?

````r
library (survival)
coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ factor(ph.ecog)+factor(sex)+ factor(age>median(lung$age)), data=lung)
#Call:
#coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ factor(ph.ecog) + factor(sex) + 
#    factor(age > median(lung$age)), data = lung)

#                                       coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z        p
#factor(ph.ecog)1                    0.40140   1.49391  0.20170  1.990  0.04658
#factor(ph.ecog)2                    0.91911   2.50705  0.23044  3.988 6.65e-05
#factor(ph.ecog)3                    1.98491   7.27840  1.03298  1.922  0.05466
#factor(sex)2                       -0.54989   0.57701  0.16838 -3.266  0.00109
#factor(age > median(lung$age))TRUE  0.08952   1.09365  0.16138  0.555  0.57910
risk = with(lung[,c('ph.ecog','sex','age')], 
   0.57910* (age > median(lung$age))
             - 0.54989* (sex==2)+ifelse (ph.ecog==1, 0.40140, ifelse(ph.ecog==2, 0.91911, 1.98491) )
            )
lung$group= risk> median(risk, na.rm=T)
plot (survfit(Surv(lung$time, lung$status)~lung$group), col= c(1,2))
```
````

Comment: Please tell us what you mean by "Risk score."  Many different things have names like this.

Comment: I am particularly asking about where the regression coefficients of Cox models and the values of covariates are used to dichotomize cases into high- and low-risk groups.